# How to build the search form in ms-access

Tags: ms-access

I have a ms-access database, now I need to build a search form on table "Samples"  .

Now, the difficulties are I need 4 search criteria, SampleNo, SampleDate,SampleClient,SampleBatchNo.

The search criterias can work together or not.

I have a listbox to show the search results, and I want to be able to select more than one records in the results set and open a new form with the limitation of the selected records only.

Thanks

Comment: How long is a piece of string? I'm afraid you need to provide more details, perhaps a subset of example criteria, before anyone will likely be able to help you out. Query by form is a really complicated topic and very specific to the particular data schema.

Comment: Thanks and will give some details of what I have already done next.

Comment: I have edit the question, and it should make better sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shuolinq,

I answered a similar question yesterday here...

[Populate list box from a table in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123616/populate-list-box-from-a-table-in-vba/1125804#1125804)

The only difference between that question and this one is that your rowsource will have multiple of those "Like" lines, one for each of your possible search terms and each pointing to a different control.

As for the second part of your question...opening a form using the selected results...that is a lot tougher.  It can be done but only with VBA code.

Seth