# How can i call the below function to populate my access form list control

Tags: sql, ms-access, forms, vba, listbox

I need to populate the access form list box from a access table.

Below is the code which I copy-pasted on button click event:

```
Public Sub PopulateLBWithData(DBPath As String, _
TableName As String, FieldName As String, _
oListControl As Object,Optional Distinct As Boolean = False, _
Optional OrderBy As String)

''#PURPOSE: Populate a list box, combo box
''#or control with similar interface with data
''#from one field in a Access Database table

''#Parameters: DBPath: FullPath to Database
''#TableName: The Name of the Table
''#FieldName: Name of the Field
''#Distinct: Optional -- True if you want distinct value
''#Order By:  Optional -- Field to Order Results by

''#Must have reference to DAO in your project

Dim sSQL As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim td As DAO.TableDef
Dim f As DAO.Field

Dim sTest As String
Dim bIsNumeric As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

On Error Resume Next

''#validate all parameters

oListControl.AddItem "a"
oListControl.Clear
If Err.Number > 0 Then Exit Sub

sTest = Dir(DBPath)
If sTest = "" Then Exit Sub

Set db = Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(DBPath)
If Err.Number > 0 Then Exit Sub

Set td = db.TableDefs(TableName)
If Err.Number > 0 Then
    db.Close
    Exit Sub
End If

Set f = td.Fields(FieldName)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        db.Close
        Exit Sub
    End If

If Len(OrderBy) Then
    Set f = td.Fields(OrderBy)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        db.Close
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

sSQL = "SELECT "
If Distinct Then sSQL = sSQL & "DISTINCT "
sSQL = sSQL & "[" & FieldName & "] FROM [" & TableName & "]"

If OrderBy <> "" Then sSQL = sSQL & " ORDER BY " & OrderBy

Set rs = db.OpenRecordSet(sSQL, dbOpenForwardOnly)

With rs
    Do While Not .EOF
        oListControl.AddItem rs(FieldName)
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With

db.Close
End Sub
```

But this function need arguments according to the VBA conventions.

Please help me how i can call this function to populate my vba form list box from the same access table?

Comment: What did you try? A *minimal* sign of commitment usually helps in getting good answers. ;) The code looks okay at first glance, you should be more clear what the actual problem is.

Comment: Did you supply the arguments?  DBPath As String, TableName As String, FieldName As String, oListControl As Object, Optional Distinct As Boolean = False, Optional OrderBy As String

Comment: i found simple solution :

lstResults.RowSource = "select * from tblTesting"

Comment: Not-so-minor quibble: On Error Resume Next is something you should almost never use and never for more than one line at a time. That is, On Error Resume Next followed by a line of code followed by On Error GoTo 0 is not terrible (though you may be discarding significant errors you didn't expect), but a whole block of code where you're ignoring all possible errors shows that your code is just complete crap.

Comment: If oListControl is a listbox on an Access form, then it should be defined as a Control, not as an Object.

Comment: If the purpose of this code is to "Populate a list box, combo box or control with similar interface with data from one field in a Access Database table" then why are you walking a recordset and using the .AddItem method of the listbox to add items, instead of just assigning the SQL string for the source recordset as the listbox/combobox's rowsource? This code looks like VB-refugee code, i.e., from someone who hasn't figured out that Access controls are significantly richer in their properties and methods than VB controls.

Answer (score 0):

That code is overly complex for what you're probably trying to do.

Why not try to just set the control's row source and then requery.

If you want to retain the parameterization, then pass in the SQL.

```
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT MyField FROM MyTable;"

Me.lstMyListBox.RowSource = strSQL
Me.lstMyListBox.Requery
```

Comment: The .Requery is entirely redundant after re-assigning the RowSource property.

Comment: Crap. I screwed up my vote -- I wanted it to be neutral, but it seems to be able to change the score on your post only +1 or -1. I've changed it back to +1, as your post is on the right track, even if the requery is not the best advice.