# Query regarding dsn string

Tags: sql, vba, forms, ms-access, listbox

Below is the code to fill a list box in a VBA application :

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

  ''#Populate list box control.
  Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim strList As String

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  ''#Use DSN to Northwind. 
  ''#Modify connection and connection string as needed.

  Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
  cnn.Open "DSN=NorthwindExample"
  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Shippers"
  Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
  rst.Open strSQL, cnn
  strList = rst.GetString(adClipString, , ";", ",")

  Debug.Print strList

  Me.lstShippers.RowSource = strList
  rst.Close
  cnn.Close
  Set rst = Nothing
  Set cnn = Nothing

  Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.No & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error"
  Set rst = Nothing
  Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I need to know what i need to put as DSN string? Where will I get the info?

What is `adClipString` here in this code?

Is there any option to populate list control without using DSN connection object since I am taking the values from the same access table?

Comment: @SmartestVEGA: This is the second question about the same topic you asked within a few minutes (the other one is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123664/) It might not be the best of ideas to keep posting random code samples you dig up in the Internet, asking people to fix them until you find one that works. You will have to invest some time into VBA if you want to get anything done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link that contains the different connection strings for Access:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

Something like this should work:  Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;

Im not sure what adClipString is, it could be an undeclared variable or database column?

Matt

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, not that great at VBA so thanks for the additional information.

Comment: I found another solution :

lstResults.RowSource = "select * from tblTesting"

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/met_rs_getstring.asp#stringformatenum) is the info on adClipString.

Basically, GetString method gets the content of the entire recordset into a string variable where columns will be separated by ";" and rows will be separated by "," (as per your code).

Regarding DSN - see Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC). One of the tab (I guess System DSN) is where ODBC based data source can be created and are listed.